# What is the method of cutting and stitching a set of images to together with Gimp?

Tags: gimp

I want to cut a cut and paste sections from different images and join them together in one rectangular image, for easy comparison. I want to be able to paste them into a single picture and use drag and drop to place the parts in the right positions, resize them, then combine them into one single image after that.

The last I tried it with Gimp it was very tedious, and I think I wasn't doing it with the appropriate tools.

What there some terms, tools and steps I need to take to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question would be easier to answer with an example or what specific issues you are having.

Here are a few general techniques:

- Use layers instead of copy and paste. You can use `File > Open as layers` to open individual files into their own layer instead of copying/pasting. You can select multiple files to do this at once.
- Use `Image > Canvas Size` to make the canvas area larger than the layers. Make sure you select to resize all the layers too. I usually double the size of the canvas and center it so there's room to work.
- Use layer groups to keep your layers organized
- Avoid merging layers unless you have to
- Use `Image > Autocrop` to make the canvas fit correctly and trip off excess canvas.

Answer (score 1):

You can use different layers and later merge them in to a single flatten image layer. In **GIMP** we can insert different images into individual layers by which we can scale,re size,re position the respective images. Later,select all the layers you want to be a single layer->Right click & select merge. This makes different layers combined in to a new merged layer. Export them as .jpg, .png etc